# Selenium picking up wrong dropdown option due to javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I have public [url](https://www.bharatpetroleum.com/Bharat-Petroleum-For/Business-Associates/dealership-data.aspx) where I am trying to test getting zone (east, west, etc) and states (country states) list in each zone. Zone dropdown drives states dropdown. Both select dropdowns have javascript. I wrote following code but the code gets me states of first zone for every subsequent zone. Not able to get correct states for a zone.

```
WebElement zoneDropDownElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ddlDealerZone'] | //select[@name='ddlDealerZone']"));
    Select zoneDropDown = new Select(zoneDropDownElement);

    //Get all options
    List<WebElement> zdd = zoneDropDown.getOptions();

    for (int j = 0; j < zdd.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(zdd.get(j).getText());
        //zoneDropDown.selectByIndex(j);

        zoneDropDown.getOptions().get(j).click();
        jse.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).change();",zoneDropDown.getOptions().get(j));
        WebElement stateDropDownElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ddlDealerState'] | //select[@name='ddlDealerState']"));
        //stateDropDownElement.click();
        jse.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).change();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ddlDealerState'] | //select[@name='ddlDealerState']")));

        Select stateDropDown = new Select(stateDropDownElement);
        List<WebElement> sdd = stateDropDown.getOptions();
        for (int k = 0; k < sdd.size(); k++) {
            System.out.println("        " + sdd.get(k).getText());
        }
```

click() should have fired javascript _doPostBack(zone,'') method. Following didn't help either.

```
jse.executeScript("_doPostBack(arguments[0],'');", zdd.get(j).getText());
```

I get following output. Same set of states are repeating for North & East zone

```
    North
        Chandigarh
        Delhi
        Haryana
        Himachal Pradesh
        Jammu and Kashmir
        Punjab
        Rajasthan
        Uttar Pradesh
        Uttrakhand
East
        Chandigarh
        Delhi
        Haryana
        Himachal Pradesh
        Jammu and Kashmir
        Punjab
        Rajasthan
        Uttar Pradesh
        Uttrakhand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript isn't the problem. You just need to wait after clicking the next value of the zones dropdown. Try the following code

```
private WebDriver driver;

@Test
public void printZoneAndStates() throws InterruptedException {
    // ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().forceCache().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://www.bharatpetroleum.com/Bharat-Petroleum-For/Business-Associates/dealership-data.aspx");
    for (int j = 0; j < getZoneDropdown().getOptions().size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(getZoneDropdown().getOptions().get(j).getText());

        getZoneDropdown().getOptions().get(j).click();
        // use implicit wait instead of an explicit one
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement stateDropDownElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ddlDealerState'] | //select[@name='ddlDealerState']"));

        Select stateDropDown = new Select(stateDropDownElement);
        List<WebElement> sdd = stateDropDown.getOptions();
        for (int k = 0; k < sdd.size(); k++) {
            System.out.println("        " + sdd.get(k).getText());
        }
    }
}

private Select getZoneDropdown() {
    return new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ddlDealerZone'] | //select[@name='ddlDealerZone']")));
}
```

As I had some StaleElementReferenceExceptions with the zones dropdown I decided to get a new instance on every usage. For my test I used an explicit wait of 3 seconds. Have a look on implicit waits and use them instead to gain performance. Tell me if that code worked for you too.

And of course my console output:

```
North
        Chandigarh
        Delhi
        Haryana
        Himachal Pradesh
        Jammu and Kashmir
        Punjab
        Rajasthan
        Uttar Pradesh
        Uttrakhand
East
        Arunachal Pradesh
        Assam
        Bihar
        Manipur
        Meghalaya
        Mizoram
        Nagaland
        Orissa
        Sikkim
        Tripura
        West Bengal
        Jharkhand
        Bhutan
West
        Dadra and  Nagar
        Daman and Diu
        Goa
        Gujarat
        Madhya Pradesh
        Maharashtra
        Chhattisgarh
South
        Andhra Pradesh
        Karnataka
        Kerala
        Pondicherry
        Tamil Nadu
        Telangana
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I came to know a good method to instantiate element to avoid stale element error. Otherwise I was doing that through some wrapper code. Thanks.